# Wrong title shown in mail from airline

Tags: bookings, wow-air

I have booked a ticket with Wow air and I got an email from them regarding change in time for flight. I noticed the mail was addressed to "MS Kumar", which indicates a female. I also checked on the flight time change confirmation page that the title is shown as "Ms", but in my ticket the title is not mentioned anywhere.

Should I reach out to the airline to rectify this or will it not cause an issue? All other details in the ticket are correct.

EDIT:

I reached out to airline and they confirmed that gender was correct but Title was incorrect which is very strange because we don't even have option of putting title while booking on wow air website. Customer care executive confirmed that title has been corrected but i have no way of verifying it.
Very strange experience...have never faced it before.

Comment: Your gender is wrong on your reservation? Is that the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since airlines are usually very careful about verifying identities, it's probably worth updating your details to avoid any day-of-travel surprises.

According to their website, ["Minor spelling errors and mistakes should go through our customer service center."](https://wowair.us/customer-service/faq/manage-booking/do-you-need-change-your-booking-details/) There's information on how to contact them in that link.